# Plugin Loads perfectly but not running when a new instance is created

Tags: plugins, rhino3d

Thanks for helping…!

I’ve compiled a rhino plugin via RhinoScriptCompiler in Rhino 7 and installed in rhino and the plugin was loaded successfully.But the commands are not working initially.

When I type the command it won’t work. But If I open the Python script editor and execute a program by debugging=ON once, then the commands are getting work.
This has to be done for everytime when we open a new instance of rhino.

I don’t know where I’m missing.

Comment: If you don’t get an answer here try asking on https://discourse.mcneel.com/ using the scripting or developer tag.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.